# How Can I Decipher This Heroku Error Message?

Tags: debugging, heroku

I am brand-new to Heroku, so this may be a novice question.  I tried pushing my app just now, and got the following message:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I opened up the log and got the message(s) below.  Judging by the change in command line's text color in the Terminal, the problem seems to be when the command line goes from "heroku[api]" to "heroku[web.1]".  But I can't say for sure.  I would love to be able to decipher Heroku messages on my own, I just need to know where to look or how to start debugging.

Thanks, everyone!

```
rickthomas$ heroku logs
2013-07-09T17:33:06.459433+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:33:06.496133+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:33:21+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-07-09T17:35:17.225189+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:35:17.676874+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY resource by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:35:17.708587+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:35:17.786263+00:00 heroku[api]: Add DATABASE_URL config by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:35:17.801350+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:35:17.846508+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ca4cf14 by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:35:17.861693+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:35:17.901985+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ca4cf14 by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:35:18+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-07-09T17:35:20.490635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 15074`
2013-07-09T17:35:21.528470+00:00 app[web.1]: The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
2013-07-09T17:35:21.528470+00:00 app[web.1]: Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:2:in `require'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120508+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120508+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120508+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120508+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120508+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120508+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/environment.rb:21:in `require': cannot load such file -- faker (LoadError)
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120508+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120508+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120508+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-07-09T17:35:23.396333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-07-09T17:35:23.410600+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-09T17:35:23.411208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-07-09T17:35:26.683935+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 57539`
2013-07-09T17:35:27.666245+00:00 app[web.1]: The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
2013-07-09T17:35:27.666245+00:00 app[web.1]: Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270486+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/environment.rb:21:in `require': cannot load such file -- faker (LoadError)
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:2:in `require'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2013-07-09T17:35:28.270736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-07-09T17:35:29.714787+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-07-09T17:35:29.731620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-09T17:37:15.135194+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=boiling-scrubland-3057.herokuapp.com fwd="74.122.9.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-09T17:37:15.526745+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=boiling-scrubland-3057.herokuapp.com fwd="74.122.9.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-09T17:37:18.534815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=boiling-scrubland-3057.herokuapp.com fwd="74.122.9.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-09T17:37:20.075790+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=boiling-scrubland-3057.herokuapp.com fwd="74.122.9.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-09T17:37:44.605357+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:37:49.741821+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by email@gmail.com
2013-07-09T17:37:18.353741+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=boiling-scrubland-3057.herokuapp.com fwd="74.122.9.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-09T17:39:03.510163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=boiling-scrubland-3057.herokuapp.com fwd="74.122.9.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-09T17:39:09.125379+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=boiling-scrubland-3057.herokuapp.com fwd="74.122.9.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-09T17:39:09.188174+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=boiling-scrubland-3057.herokuapp.com fwd="74.122.9.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
Ricks-MacBook-Pro:even_awesomer_blog_soon_to_be_hacker_news rickthomas$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep-diving into the logs, the closest I could come to an error message was:

```
2013-07-09T17:35:22.120319+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/environment.rb:21:in `require': cannot load such file -- faker (LoadError)
```

I simply commented out the references to the "Faker" gem in my gemfile and environment.rb file, and re-deployed it to Heroku.  This worked fine.

Lesson learned- Heroku and Faker don't play well together.

Answer (score 0):

Might also try in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'faker', require: false
```

And then specifically require it where necessary.